# Serializable transaction isolation with multiple statements

Tags: sql, t-sql

I don't have a database supporting serializable transaction isolation to play with, but I wanted to understand something about it. If I `insert` a new row into a empty table and then do a `select count` from the same table within the same transaction; will the result be 0 or 1?

Update:
According to this page https://my.vertica.com/docs/4.1/HTML/Master/2887.htm

> It also sees the results of updates run within its transaction, even
>   if they have not been committed.

True or false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will.

Within a serialized transaction your view of the database is consistent with all changes you have made within the transaction.